# Algebraic Way to Prove $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{(2n)!}{((n-r)!)^2(r!)^2} = \binom{2n}{n}^2$

Tags: summation

$\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{(2n)!}{((n-r)!)^2(r!)^2} = \binom{2n}{n}^2$

This identity can be easily proven by mathematical induction.

However, is there any algebraic way to sum it up to $\binom{2n}{n}^2$?

Comment: Write this as $\frac{2n!}{n!^2}{n\choose r}^2$. Also , $\frac{2n!}{n!^2}={2n\choose n}$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $$\frac{(2n)!}{((n-r)!)^2(r!)^2}=\frac{(n!)^2}{((n-r)!)^2(r!)^2}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}\binom{n}{r}^2$$ Therefore, $$\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{(2n)!}{((n-r)!)^2(r!)^2}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{n}{r}^2=\binom{2n}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}^2=\binom{2n}{n}^2$$

Where $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$$ follows from [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).